# Gpio export fails

Tags: pi-3, gpio

Trying to build Blink application from Visual Studio sample for PI. Build system runs command `sudo gpio export 17 out`

Command return error:

```
gpio: Unable to open GPIO direction interface for pin 17: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with this command and how to fix it?

Comment: add more info to your question: model Pi, OS + version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are running a recent kernel that has finally removed the long deprecated `sysfs` GPIO interface.

You could either build a custom kernel with CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS enabled or switch to the new(er) GPIO character device userspace API, so **libgpiod** and its associated tools in the **gpiod** package.  Of those, `gpioset` is used to set a line as output.